# Loading an Angular2 Component Dynamically from a Remote Gist

Tags: angular

Anyone know if it's possible to load a component from a remote source without using SystemJS. The [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/IpQ2HRa7yBj2YKZdgBZl?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts) here is using System JS `(System.import(url))` to load the component but I'm using Webpack. I naively tried using SystemJS lib in my Webpack setup to load the component but I got a lot of errors. I assume due to me not having a SystemJs config file.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I'm trying to implement a pluggable design, where components are dynamically loaded from a server.

Comment: Hi guys, any update on this one ?